# StringVar Callback with Unique Identifier?

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, trace, tkinter-entry

I am storing a matrix of Entries, each attached to a unique `StringVar`. On the callback for the `StringVar`, I want to be able to find which `StringVar` it was, with respect to the matrix.  This is what I have:

```
    def callback(sv, index):    
        print index

    for i in range(ncols):
        for j in range(self.nrows):
            sv = StringVar()
            uniqueId = str(i)+str(j)
            sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: callback(sv, uniqueId))
            self.results[i][j] = Entry(gridtable,textvariable=sv,bg='grey',borderwidth=1,fg='black',width=self.widget_width).grid(row=j+2,column=i+1,sticky='ew')
```

However, it **always** prints the same index ('718' - which is '7'+'18': the values that i and j stop at). How can I get a unique identifier for these `StringVars`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sv` variable is changing in your code, but `uniqueID` is getting stuck at the last value it's given. You can set it to remember its value on that iteration of the loop by including it in the lambda expression, like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

def callback(var, index):
    print var, index

root = Tk()

for i in range(10):
    var = StringVar()
    uniqueID = i
    var.trace('w', lambda name,index,mode, var=var, uniqueID=uniqueID: callback(var, uniqueID))
    Entry(root, textvariable=var).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! That is perfect. Can you explain what the lambda is doing in this case? In other words, how does this solve it?

Comment: By adding `var=var` and `ID=ID`, you're assigning default values to the arguments when they're created. Without the default value, the `trace` method invokes the command with the current value of `uniqueID`, which will be the last value it was given.